# Как вывести значение переменной в CMD?

Tags: cmd

Хочу присвоить значение переменной `audiolen`. ffprobe корректно считает время, но значение не сохраняется в переменную. Что не так?

```
SET audiolen = ffprobe -i start.mp4 -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0"
echo %audiolen%
```

Comment: я конечно сто лет с cmd не работал, но возможно это из-за пробелов вокруг знака равенства?

Comment: нашел [вопрос с ответами на английском SE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10552812/10666424)

Comment: Невозможно присвоить в переменную вывод программы командой SET - даже если программа любезно льёт его в выходной поток. Следует использовать конструкцию типа `for /f %x in 'ffprobe -i start.mp4 -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0"' do set audiolen=%x`. И надеяться, что программа не залепит в выходной поток пустую строку (или проверять и игнорировать).